# Is Cloud Pub/Sub region specific - Data movement and message store managed within the region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

In the context of GDPR (Data residency), the data movement and storage is restricted to the region from where the data gets originated. This data cannot be moved from this region for any purpose, be it for fail-over replication or backup. Is Cloud Pub/Sub compliant with this requirement. The document does not guarantee concretely anywhere. 
This answer to this question is the DEAL maker/breaker for Cloud Pub/Sub.
thanks, Raghavendra Prakash.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this part of the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#basic_architecture

As stated pub/sub is a global services. But if you read a bit more, you can see that there is a garantee of message deletion when the treatment ends here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#data_plane_-_the_life_of_a_message

This should assure that no datas stays inside the pub/sub service.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Pub/Sub now supports controlling where your message data is stored.  See: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/resource-location-restriction